# mysqli_query not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the php:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","foo","bar","quaz");
if($con){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `virtual_users` (`domain_id`, `password` , `email`) 
    VALUES ('2', ENCRYPT('".$password."', CONCAT('\$6\$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))), '".$user."@".$domain."');";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if(!$query){
        echo $sql;
    }else{
        echo "Success adding new email user!";
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run this query it always returns `$sql`. *This means that the connection is fine but the query is not.*

When I then run the the echo of `$sql` directly on the mysql database it works perfectly!! I have no idea what is going wrong! Any ideas?

Comment: `$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));` -- Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. no idea where your variables are coming from.

Comment: no idea, ask the downvoter, not me

Comment: [oh and you're welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580529/mysqli-query-not-working-as-expected#comment49230926_30580529). Had of known, I'd of made that an answer. ;-) obviously my comment was just as good as gold.

Comment: Haha it was an open question!!

Comment: I have been downvoted before when posting just an error checking as an answer. Nope, not going there anymore. *Live & learn* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you should be outputting the reason for the failure, not the query that caused the failure:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There's exactly **ONE** way for a query to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. Just having "valid" sql means nothing.

Comment: Thank you!! I got the error `INSERT command denied to user 'quaz'@'localhost' for table 'virtual_users'`!!

Comment: So there you go. your user doesn't have the rights to do inserts on that table.